# How do I share a resource between multiple threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I share an array of a class between multiple threads in Java?

Say I have a class called Input with an array as below:

```
public class Input {
    int index;
    int[] input = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

    public Input(){
        index = 0;
    }

    public void print(int index){
        System.out.println(input[index]);
    }

    synchronized public int getIndex(){
        if(index == 15)
            return -1;
        return index++;
    }

}
```

Now, I want 2 threads to share the array of Input class, and print the elements of the array (i.e) both the threads together should print 15 times (the number of elements in the array) in total.

This is my thread class:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

    Thread t;
    int index;
    Input ip;

    public MyThread(Input ip, String name){
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        this.ip = ip;
        index = 0;
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        while((index=ip.getIndex())!=-1){
            System.out.println(t.getName());
            ip.print(index);
        }

    }   

}
```

And finally, the code which sets up the threads:

```
public class Caller {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Input ip = new Input();
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(ip, "Thread1");
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(ip, "Thread2");
        t1.t.join();
        t2.t.join();

    }

}
```

The output should be something like:

Thread1

1

Thread2

2

Thread2

3

Thread1

4

Thread2

5

and so on till it reaches the last element in the array.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what you have should be OK, but as this is a trivial class and you are using a Synchronized method in the main part of you loop, probably Thread1 finishes before Thread2 gets a chance.

Comment: Oh yea, it does seem to work for larger arrays. Sorry about that. But now the output looks like this: Thread1 Thread2 2 1 Thread1 3 (the name of thread gets printed multiple times). Also, how do I make them alternate without putting sleep?

Comment: "How do I make them alternate...?"  That's not what threads are for.  If you think you want to control which thread executes when, then you probably want to write single-threaded code.  Use threads when you want to perform tasks in parallel, where "parallel" means, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Also notice that you're setting `index = 0` on the same `Input` object `ip`. There are chances that `Thread1` has already started execution (printing values) before even `Thread2` is created. So you might see duplicate values printed on some runs. Since you're already setting `index = 0` in the `ip` constructor, there is no need to do it again in the `MyThread` I believe. Or you could `start()` the threads only after you've created both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your threads have synchronized access to `Input.index`, so the `Input` class is fine. Your real problem lies in `MyThread.run`. These two lines:

```
    System.out.println(t.getName());
    ip.print(index);
```

make 2 separate calls to `System.out.println`. In a multithreaded context, they are bound to be interleaved between threads, hence the output will be out of (global) order.

If you want to guarantee that the 2 calls are inseparable, you need to make this 2 calls sort of "atomic" (like a synchronization block). You'll have to share a lock between your threads to protect access to this code block and make their execution mutual exclusive. They can share either an intrinsic lock on a lock `Object`, or an explicit lock by using `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`.

I'm giving a sample code for an intrinsic lock:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

    Input ip;
    Object lock;

    public MyThread(Input ip, Object lock){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int index = -1;     
        while((index=ip.getIndex())!=-1){
            synchronized(lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                ip.print(index);
            }
        }
    }   
}


public class Caller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Input ip = new Input();
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread(ip, lock), "Thread1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread(ip, lock), "Thread2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Please note: this will only ensure that "ThreadX n" will print together. It does not guarantee that the output follows the exact order in the `Input` array.

BTW, starting a `Thread` in the constructor is dangerous and should be avoided. I made minor changes to your original code.

Comment: "...starting a Thread in the constructor is dangerous" because it potentially allows the thread to access the object before the object has been fully initialized.  That is also known as "leaking _this_" or "unsafe publication."  The Java language spec says that the state of an object as seen by other threads is _undefined_ if the other thread(s) gets hold of a reference to the object before the object's constructor has returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach using low-level wait-notify methods.

```
package com.thread;

/*Print 1 to 15 together by 2 threads*/

public class Print1To15 {

    static int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(input);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(input);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(t1, "Thread 1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(t2, "Thread 2");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
    int[] array;
    static int i = 0;
    final static Object obj = new Object();

    MyThread(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            while (i <= 14) {
                if (array[i] % 2 != 0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread 1")) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " printing " + array[i]);
                    try {
                        obj.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread 2")) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " printing " + array[i]);
                    try {
                        obj.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                i++;
                obj.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```